# Why anchor tag is taking extra white space?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am working on react project, In that I have an anchor tag, then I have a navbar.
The problem is anchor tag is pushing navbar to right side. Because anchor tag is taking the extra white space. 
I've  even tried to use `display: 'inline-block'`, and it isn't working.

`Navbar.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Navbar.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Navbar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='container-fluid custom'>
                <div className='container'>
                    <div className='row'>
                        <div className='col-12'>
                            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                                <a className="navbar-brand space" href="www.facebook.com">
                                    <div className='logo'>
                                        <img src='assets/images/kaboom.png' alt='logo'></img>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                    <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                                </button>
                                <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                                    <ul className="navbar-nav">
                                        <li className="nav-item active">
                                            <Link className='nav-link' to='/'>Home</Link>
                                        </li>
                                        <li className="nav-item">
                                            <Link className='nav-link' to='/register'>Register</Link>
                                        </li>
                                        <li className="nav-item">
                                            <Link className='nav-link' to='/login'>Login</Link>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Navbar
```

This is Navbar.css

```
.logo {
    width: 10%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.logo img {
    width: 100%;
}

.space {
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```

Comment: For white-space issues, including a working example in your question is pretty critical.

Comment: Hi DBS, can you please tell me how to overcome this?

Comment: post a working example. This is extremely vague... Create a sandbox at https://codesandbox.io and share with us

Comment: Code sandbox works, but it's best to create an interactive stack snippet here.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-wind-lpwjo

Answer (score 1):

it would be better if you could provide us a snippet or something but anyway
you can find out what causing the white space using any browser's developers tools
it might be a margin or padding, just open it and point to your element to find out and then you can resolve the issue by applying  `margin:0` or `padding:0` to that element
hope I could be a help!

Comment: in addition you could set: position: absolute; so it does not take any whitespace at all, and visibility: hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use div inside of anchor tag. Just wrap the logo in an anchor tag and give whatever width to that img tag.
Like this:

```
<a className="navbar-brand space"  href="www.facebook.com">
    <img src='assets/images/kaboom.png' width="150" alt='logo'></img>
</a>
```